# Groupy Pandas DataFrame with Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to groupby on a single field, then get the nlargest(14) records on a date field, then get the mean of another field, and I am getting stuck on the logic.

```py
data = [['NRB000043', nan, None, Timestamp('2020-01-27 00:00:00')],
 ['NRB000042', nan, None, Timestamp('2020-01-27 00:00:00')],
 ['483951076', nan, None, Timestamp('2020-01-27 00:00:00')],
 ['080699991', nan, None, Timestamp('2020-01-27 00:00:00')],
 ['NRB000045', nan, None, Timestamp('2020-01-27 00:00:00')],
 ['530639995', 23.0, None, Timestamp('2020-01-27 00:00:00')],
 ['530639997', 24.0, None, Timestamp('2020-01-27 00:00:00')]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['sid', 'measure', 'co_unit', 'timedate'])

series = df.groupby('sid')['timedate'].nlargest(14)
```

So this is what I have, but I am stuck trying to get the mean of the `measure` field.  Can someone please assist me with the proper logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Also what is expected output DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) method:

```
df.groupby('sid').agg({'timedate': lambda x: x.nlargest(14),
                       'measure': 'mean'})

print(df)

            timedate  measure
sid                          
080699991 2020-01-27      NaN
483951076 2020-01-27      NaN
530639995 2020-01-27     23.0
530639997 2020-01-27     24.0
NRB000042 2020-01-27      NaN
NRB000043 2020-01-27      NaN
NRB000045 2020-01-27      NaN
```

Comment: I think so. based on the question, the user is stuck on doing aggregate on multiple fields `timedate, measure`.

Comment: because I think it is problem chain functions returned series and returned scalar